# 504 gateway timeout - openstack dashboard?

Tags: apache2, ubuntu-16.04, openstack

I tried to configure a all-in-one node setup for openstack. I configured each component one by one and every component seems to be working, except for horizon.

Now when trying to load the openstack dashboard, I get a timeout error.

I am a beginner - any help/hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you can share some more information about your setup with us (e.g. OS etc.)?

Comment: Thanks for helping me out.I found the answer.

Comment: what was the answer please , I am facing the same error with ceilometer

Answer (score 1):

solved the problem as below:

1)Edit the dashboard configuration file:

`vim /etc/apache2/conf-available/openstack-dashboard.conf`

2)Add the following line to the configuration:

**WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}**

3) Reload apache

`service apache2 reload`

Used this [link](https://ask.openstack.org/en/question/100625/solved-gateway-timeout-error-cannot-access-horizon-on-openstack-newton/) as reference.